# ¿Porqué el string.default_web_client_id se mantiene en rojo?

Tags: firebase, google-api

buenas estoy realizando una aplicación y quiero autenticar con google y facebook de firebase, todo ha estado bien hasta que realice una actualización del android studio a la v4 y ahora el *R.string.default_web_client_id* se mantiene en rojo.
lei que podria ser algo del ID así que he realizado toda la aplicación de nuevo y aún sigue apareciendo.
Gracias

```
public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

private SignInButton signInButton;

public static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 777;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);

    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

    signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_DARK);

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
        }
    });


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                goMainScreen();
            }
        }
    };

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(result.getSignInAccount());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_log_in, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(signInAccount.getIdToken(), null);
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.not_firebase_auth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void goMainScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (firebaseAuthListener != null) {
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo el json también en su lugar y también la implementación. Cuando genero APK sale normal el APK para probarlo en mi celular, pero sigue rojo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal por el cual no puede resolver

```
R.string.default_web_client_id
```

Se debe a configuración, debes agregar el archivo `google-services.json` dentro del directorio `/app`

Ademas asegura la configuración de tu archivo `/app/build.gradle` indicada en la documentación.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services
```

Revisa:
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: me genera el APK para probar en el celular todo normal, tambien tiene las dependencias y el  plugin. pero sigue rojo. gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Esto sucede porque la referencia al String se crea al compilar el proyecto y de forma automática. El IDE no es capaz de alcanzarlo sin antes compilar. No se preocupe por eso, el programa funcionará igualmente.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso también me salía en rojo, y se solucionó al cambiar la versión en el gradle. Estaba en 30 y la pasé a 32.

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 32

  default config {
  targetSdkVersion 32
  }
}
```